# Can I say "voted polls" to mean the polls I have voted in?

Tags: adjectives, expressions, past-participles

How can I correctly identify polls I have voted in?

Is “voted polls” right? Or there is a better way?

Answer (score 7):

"Polls taken", "completed polls", "polls you participated in", "polls you are done with", or in fact your very own "polls you have voted in".

"Voted polls", in the intended meaning, is ungrammatical. You do not vote polls. *Vote* in that meaning is intransitive. When it's transitive, it specifies the thing you voted *for*. So, "voted polls" means "I voted for polls" (e.g., as opposed to other people who voted against having said polls). If I saw it as the title of a table column, or whatever it is you seem to be labeling, I would expect that column to contain the number of people who voted for polls.

Comment: “You do not vote *anything*” is wrong because phrases like “He voted Republican” are common.

Comment: @jwpat7: I think “He voted Republican” could be seen as "adverbial" (he voted *in a Republican manner*), so ЯegDwight's assertion is still technically valid (he said *any **thing***, not *any **way** / manner*).

Comment: I think it's clearly a complement, not an adverb.  (By the way, your example, which does not demonstrate adverbial use, does not work for *He voted Democrat.* / **He voted in a Democrat manner.*)

Comment: @jwpat7 but that is precisely what I'm saying. Look at the sentence in context. Look at the very next sentence. Perhaps I should regroup it somehow if it causes such confusion, but I do wonder why it would cause any confusion at all unless it were a standalone sentence, like in your comment, which it is not.

Comment: ЯegDwight, by “that is precisely what I'm saying” do you mean you are saying
«“You do not vote *anything”* is wrong because phrases like “He voted Republican” are common» exactly?  If so, why not edit the answer and take out the sentence that's misleading, “You do not vote *anything”*?

Comment: @jwpat7 yeah, short and sweet. Done.

Answer (score 1):

(Polls) voted on - would be used in a simple sentence.

Comment: That feels awkward to use in a sentence, because it doesn't say who did the voting. I could see it as an item on a form.